# Printing out multiple values assigned to a single variable

Tags: java

I have a for loop that will continue until i is not less than the maxnum as shown in the code. In the meantime it will do modulo operation and I am trying to accumulate as much values as possible to the variable that I can assign with. My problem is in the code is that it only does the single operation and will not continue to do the operation and have multiple values assign to it. Should I change my loop.

tried assigning an array list
having i++ below

```
 for(int i =1; i < maxnum; i++ ) {
    MulT = i % divisor;

    }

 if ( MulT==0 ) {

        System.out.println("Multiples of " + dividend+ " between 1 and "+ maxnum +" is");
        System.out.println(MulT);

    } 
else {
      System.out.println("Multiples of " + dividend +  " between 1 and " + maxnum+ "are:");
       System.out.print("No numbers were found");
   }
```

Multiples of 2 between 1 and 10  are:

2
4
6
8
10

Comment: where is your arraylist? you said you have tried.

Comment: you need to put your **if-else statement** inside your for loop, to get all values

Comment: also if you need multiple of suppose 2 then you need to print value of **i** not **MulT** .

Comment: @Swati thanks for the tip it is printing the desired numbers but it is also printing the else statement if no multiples were found

Comment: remove **else** part then , only keep **if condition**

Comment: @Swati I need it for examples such as Max 8 and dividend 10 where its not possible

Comment: then put condition above your **for** loop **if(max > dividend)** then only enter for loop else print something

Comment: Note that you should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable names always start with lowercase. For example `MulT` should be `mulT`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all the values stored in variables then you have to iterate that variable in for loop after that print that variable in console, check the below code.

```
  int maxnum=10;
  int divisor=2;
  int  val[] = new int[maxnum];
  int j=0;

  for(int i =1; i <= maxnum; i++ ) {
    double MulT = i % divisor;          
        if(MulT==0){            
            val[j]=i;
            j++;
        }
  }
  if(val[0] > 0){
      System.out.print("Multiples of " + divisor+ " between 1 and "+ maxnum +" is:");
      for(int k=0;k < val.length;k++){
          if(val[k]!=0){
              System.out.print(" "+val[k]);
          }
      }
  }else{
      System.out.println("Multiples of " + divisor +  " between 1 and " + maxnum+" are:");
      System.out.print("No numbers were found");
  }
```